# How to test Virtual Display on Android?

Tags: android

I am working on creating Virtual Display in an android app.

`DisplayManager displayManager = (DisplayManager) getSystemService(Context.DISPLAY_SERVICE);
VirtualDisplay virtualDisplay = displayManager.createVirtualDisplay("Test Display", 1000 /* width /, 1000 / height */, DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT, null, DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_PRESENTATION);`

How can I render content on this display and verify ?

I have created a demo presentation with this and trying to load a webview there but not seeing any effect on app screen.

Comment: Can anyone suggest what is missing from this question ?

Answer (score 6):

1. Permission Needed :- `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.
2. Create `MediaProjectionManager`
3. `StartActivityForResult` with `createScreenCapture` intent
4. `OnActivityResult` create `MediaProjection` with callback
5. Create `ImageReader` (Take `PixelFormat` `RGBA_8888` as parameter)
6. Register callbacks on `ImageReader` to capture screen shot.
7. Create `VirtualDisplay` with `ImageReader` surface
8. Create `DisplayListener` to get callbacks on whenever new displays are added, removed or modified
9. Register `DisplayListener` with `DisplayManager`
10. `OnDisplayChanged` event of `DisplayListener` Create a presentation and show it
11. Create a class for sample presentation which shows a layout
12. When `Presentation` is shown, you get notification on `onImageAvailable` api of callback registered with `ImageReader`
13. On `Notification`, capture the image from `ImageReader` and save it to sdcard.

P.S :- This question is asked by me and I have answered myself, please let me know if you need more details on this question and answer.

Comment: I want to project the head unit in car dashboard to rear seat displays. I am thinking of using this virtual display technology. Where can I find more documents or sample projects related to virtual display. If you have any link please send me. @Vineet Setia

Comment: @TheHound.developer hello :) were you able to figure this out? If so, could you share the resources that helped you :)

Comment: Can you please clarify if VirtualDisplay's target surface is ImageReader's surface? I mean Virtual Display draws on to ImageReader's surface? Anyways to draw to VirtualDisplay manually other than media projection?

Answer (score 0):

Enable Simulate secondary displays in the developer option on your phone.